# Web development using Raku

Tags: raku

I want to know if web development can be done using Raku or Perl6?

Like Django for Python, do we have any framework available for Raku?

Id appreciate if you told us which are the libraries available or any tutorial.

Are there any webhosting providers to host Raku web application?

Answer (score 28):

Many folks are using [Cro](https://cro.services/) for this. It's a set of libraries that you can pick as needed (and not just for web development), but offers things like:

- [Routing](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-router) requests to handlers, and neat ways to express those handlers
- [WebSocket support](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-router-websocket) integrated neatly into the router
- [Templating](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-webapp-template)
- [Testing](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-test)

There's a [simple tutorial](https://cro.services/docs/intro/http-server) as well as a [much longer one on making a SPA](https://cro.services/docs/intro/spa-with-cro).
There is also a fresh [CRUD server-side tutorial](https://rakuadventcalendar.wordpress.com/2019/12/02/crud-cro-http-tutorial/) available.

Finally, there's integrated support in the [Comma IDE](https://commaide.com/), which includes a Cro project template where you can select the bits you need, indexing of and navigation to routes, and a timeline view that can be used to understand where time is spent during request processing.

There are base images available to support [Docker deployment](https://cro.services/docs/docker-deployment) also, to anywhere that supports that.

Comment: Unfortunately, development of the Comma IDE ceased Feb 09, 2024. Although there appears to be some discussion about continuing the development of the Comma plugin for IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 6):

I built a web framework for Raku called [Humming-Bird](https://github.com/rawleyfowler/Humming-Bird) it's brand new so there are still kinks to work out, but the core works really well! It is intended to be very similar to [Sinatra](https://sinatrarb.com/) and other frameworks of that style (express.js etc..)

Humming-Bird has most of the typical features of a web framework including but not limited to:

- Routing
- Middleware
- Serving static files

This project is still in fairly early stages, but it offers more than enough to spin up simple web services, and web apps.

Comment: Looks like Humming-Bird is coming along nicely!